# Cannot scrape data from website in for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

[image] I am trying to scrape a real estate site in Greece from multiple locations of Athens, the site use some kind of protection so I am using cookies and headers always(I know I must rotate the user agent so I will not be blocked this will be the next step, because I must always change my IP to scrape (soz because I am newbie still on scrapy)).

Each page of the site shows 10 flats, the loop iterates correct in the first 4 and afterwards returns [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.spitogatos.gr/aggelia/1111057856>](https://www.spitogatos.gr/aggelia/1111057856%3E) (referer: https://www.spitogatos.gr/pwliseis-katoikies/athina-notia-proastia/)

so what I am doing wrong and I cannot scrape the remaining flats correctly as the first??

```
import scrapy

class MainprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'mainProject'
allowed_domains = ['www.spitogatos.gr']    
download_delay = 5.0
headers = {
    "authority": "www.spitogatos.gr",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,el-GR;q=0.8,el;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6"
}

cookies = {
"PHPSESSID": "946hl5lpbcf6jalm271g2450u8",
"spitogatosHomepageMap": "0",
"currentCurrency": "EUR",
"_ga": "GA1.2.1080968683.1626031679",
"_gid": "GA1.2.1871094347.1627582033",
"_hjTLDTest": "1",
"_hjid": "66a31a57-9c80-47f1-8767-9bca91d47b1f",
"_fbp": "fb.1.1626031679317.910543448",
"__qca": "P0-1840509725-1625417320200",
"_hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress": "0",
"openedTabs": "1",
"_gat_UA-3455846-10": "1",
"_gat_UA-3455846-2": "1",
"_hjIncludedInSessionSample": "1",
"reese84": "3:5Stu7C2tUWBSIdWSdzMOSQ==:ppmbagk94sf6IvvS66908AApyTMfCE+K7i7PgkeyRs6C9VGkCcqBSz8ZsgbOx56c46ktjL+1iyfp8zL1PuiT7AUsmA9XLdcmMoDQm30MnEPgcbQl/dMQV1PgqtVJgWVwGabZlMhGM+T6D8zf5ENVuGhLJ81U74a+gr+GySA5Xx/CqUPcGa/YG2zNICEMnZN7D4bRwJq6vxEvOU+wbSfAE6OquI4ipeHR3dz8jBwY961ka2PfY7MoLCLeGdzPUu07yOxv41lvdcZbaj9/peyxLnLSFqD9QnV5MXsXy7mKE3eNoT46F/ITB8/GAVpc/zqW792F+7HuUkWJD/pWaNOsr6+rc75kpKw15xtN5oCw9Qh3Fw9SYUtfbFMTRXBrUt0Ow/Lv2C3oOLBQyVex80cr76c4ibxS/niuNvKA87f7XZc=:THUtE26ivNhlKtaznqNuX7swpAf4x5S8pF+xoBg5KwE="
[![enter image description here][1]][1]}

#start_urls = ['https://www.spitogatos.gr/']
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://www.spitogatos.gr/pwliseis-katoikies/athina-notia-proastia/'
    yield  scrapy.Request(
        url=url,
        method='GET',
        cookies=self.cookies,
        headers=self.headers,
        callback= self.parse,
    )
def parse(self, response):
   print(response.xpath('//span[@class="tile-v5-sr__details-price"]/text()').extract()) 
   houses = response.xpath('//h4[@class="tile-v5-sr__title"]')
   print("houses"+str(len(houses)))
   for house in houses:
       link = house.xpath('.//@href').get()
       print(link)
       yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_housing, meta={'description': "name"},
                             headers = self.headers, cookies= self.cookies)
       
#   next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a@href").get()
  # if next_page:
                #   yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse, meta={'description': "name"},
                         #    headers = self.headers, cookies= self.cookies)

       
       
                                     
def parse_housing(self, response):  #just dummy prints
   name = response.request.meta['description']
   print("hello")
   print(response.xpath('.//h6[@class="line__text nowrap"]/text()').extract())
   print(response.xpath('.//div[@class="line"]/h6/text()').extract())#tetragonika metra
   yield  (response.xpath('.//h6[@class="line__text nowrap"]/text()').extract())
```

Comment: First of all scrapy handles cookies by default so you don't need to worry about this. Second, the problem is that the website use a strong anti-scraping techniques. After 4 urls they block you for some time. The first thing to do is to get a token from 'https://www.spitogatos.gr/69616d7761746368696e67796f75?d=www.spitogatos.gr', you can try simulate the request to scrape the token. Another option is to use scrapy with a headless browser, or scrapy-splash.

Comment: thanks for the comment I appreciate it!

Comment: @georgekasa I would also be interested in the crawler, did you find a workaround after all?

Comment: I tried with selenium much better, but again I encounter problems like captcha.